# cannot update, cannot reinstall dkms

Tags: apt, updates, dkms

I wasn't too surprised that I would need to reinstall the virtualbox-dkms business.  But I can't do that this morning, as the result of my apt-get update is:

I wasn't too surprised that I would need to reinstall the virtualbox-dkms business.  But I can't do that this morning, as the result of my `apt-get update` is:

```
gn http:gpackages.medibuntu.org precise/free Translation-en                                             
Ign http:gpackages.medibuntu.org precise/non-free Translation-en_US                                      
Ign http:gpackages.medibuntu.org precise/non-free Translation-en                                         
Fetched 366 kB in 9s (38.4 kB/s)                                                                         
Reading package lists... Done
W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: mirror:gmirrors.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2

W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: mirror:gmirrors.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2

W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: mirror:gmirrors.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2

W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: mirror:gmirrors.ubuntu.com precise-security Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2

W: Failed to fetch mirror:gmirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/dists/precise/Release   

W: Failed to fetch mirror:gmirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/dists/precise-updates/Release   

W: Failed to fetch mirror:gmirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/dists/precise-backports/Release   

W: Failed to fetch mirror:gmirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/dists/precise-security/Release   

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```